# How to send data to an ASP.NET Controller with Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a controller that has a `Create` action. Its purpose is to receive a name and data from file form, and `IndexViewModel` return `IEnumerable<File>` files.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    static List<Models.File> files = new List<Models.File>();

    public HomeController() { }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index() => View(new IndexViewModel { Files = files });

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create() => View();

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(IFormFile file)
    {
        var filename = 
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition)
                                         .FileName;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            files.Add(new Models.File { Name = filename, Data = content });
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

When I use a form in static **html**, it's alright, the server receives the data. But when I use the same form in an **Angular2** template it doesn't.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {File} from './file';


@Component({
    selector: 'listfile',
    template: `
<form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Api/File" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" #newFile (keyup.enter)="addFile(newFile.value)"
    (blur)="addFile(newFile.value); newFile.value='' ">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
    <table class="table">
        <th>id</th><th>name</th>
        <tr *ngFor="#file of files"> 
            <td>{{file.id}}</td>
            <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
    `
})
export class ListFileComponent {
    files = [
        new File(1, 'file1'),
        new File(2, 'file2')
    ];
    addFile(newFile: string) {
        if (newFile) {
            this.files.push(new File(this.files.length + 1, newFile.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop()))
        }
    }
    falert(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misconception of the **Angular2** templating and the **MVC** pre-processing. [Here is a post](https://ievangelistblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/building-an-angular2-spa-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-2-and-typescript-1-7-5/) that might clear that up. You have **ASP.NET** tag helpers that will not be rendered on the server, and instead will be sent to the client as is.

You are using the [form post which passes form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data), instead you should be using the **Web API** with **Angular2's** [Http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html) service.

You have many options, but two of them are the most practical at this point:

1. You can choose to use the power of **MVC** for its pre-processing and have a partial view return the form. In your component you use the `templateUrl` instead of the `template` and point to the `/controller/action` that would pre-process the tag helpers and return the HTML as desired (this would then serve as an **Angular2** template.
2. You can start leveraging **Angular2** as a true **SPA**, and only use MVC to serve a single page ever... `/home/index`. Then you use the `templateUrl` to point to local `.html` files that serve as the template. And build out an API that will support all the interactions you need.

I hope this clears things up!

---

If you are going to use the inline or the static `.html` you'll need to remove the **ASP.NET** tag helpers.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'listfile',
    template: `
<form (submit)="" >
    <input type="file" name="files" #newFile (keyup.enter)="addFile(newFile.value)"
    (blur)="addFile(newFile.value); newFile.value='' ">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
    <table class="table">
        <th>id</th><th>name</th>
        <tr *ngFor="#file of files"> 
            <td>{{file.id}}</td>
            <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
    `
})
export class ListFileComponent {
    // ...
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    onSubmit() {
       const body = JSON.stringify({ this.files });
       this.http
           .post('api/file/create', 
                 body, 
                 { headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }) })
           .map(response => response.json())
           .subscribe(json => { /* handle it */ });
    }
}
```

Then you'd have to change your API signature to more accurately accept the data.

Comment: Thank your for answer, got it, great post!
I think the second option is nicer.